# About thermal diffusion in air and water

Tags: thermodynamics, statistics, diffusion

I have a fairly simple question:

Why does heat spread faster in air than in water? For me it is counterintuitive compared to the higher thermal conductivity of water. The only "empirical" answer I have is that density in air is lower. Therefore heat conduction happens faster in a given volume in air just because there are less molecules which have to "conduct" the heat. This then makes air a spatially faster conductor than water (which has higher density and therefore more molecules must conduct the heat).

But I don't know how to account for that mathematically.

More specific:
For the boundary condition of a initial heat point source, Ficks 2nd law is solved by a gaussian with standart deviation $σ$. The spatial standart deviation of a molecular random walk is given through $σ=\sqrt{2Dt}$, where $D$ is the thermal diffusivity (which is also given by $D=\frac{λ}{ρc_p}$, where $λ$ is the thermal conductivity)

From [thermal diffusivity of air](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-thermal-diffusivity-d_2011.html) and [water](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-steam-thermal-diffusivity-d_2058.html) I got the values at 300K and normal pressure.

Thermal diffusivity $D$ of air: $22.6 * 10^6 \frac{m^2}{s}$
and water: $0.1463 * 10^6 \frac{m^2}{s}$

Ok, so then after a given time the heat is more spread out in air! How can I show this? And of course, what are the environmental consequences of this, condsidering the ocean and the atmosphere?

Comment: Are you looking for a molecular-level explanation for why diffusivity of air is greater than that of water ?

Comment: I don't know what the diffusivity exactly means physically, therefore I'm more interested what consequences it has on real diffusion. The spatial standart deviation is a clear observable quantity. If it is true that air is more spread out in water after a given time, why does everyone just say that air conducts worse. To put it another way, what is our understanding of conductivity, when it is not how fast heat is transported across spatial distances , which seems to be GREATER in air than in water!!

Comment: Sorry of course I meant: If it is true that heat is more spread out in air than in water after a given time